# VHDL Code Error: "Error (10818): Can't infer register for <name> at <location> because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge"

Tags: vhdl, digital, quartus

I know this error has been encountered several times on SO, but as a beginner I am still unable to see how to solve this error in my own code. The error and code are both printed below, thank you to anyone for their input.

> Error (10818): Can't infer register for count[0] at 5bit_PHreg_vhdl.vhd(21) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge

The error is repeated for each bit of 'count' and refers to the line noted in the code.

```
ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF 5bit_PHreg_vhdl IS
SIGNAL count    :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN
    PROCESS(reset, clk, SHR_EN)
        BEGIN
-- Check if asynchronous reset is 0
        IF reset = '0' THEN --ERROR OCCURS HERE
                count <= "00000";
-- Check if rising edge
        ELSIF (clk'EVENT AND clk = '1') THEN
                IF LD_EN = '1' THEN
                    count <= FA_in;
                END IF;
-- Check if SHR_EN is active
        ELSIF (SHR_EN = '1') THEN
                count(4) <= c_in;
                count(3) <= count(4);
                count(2) <= count(3);
                count(1) <= count(2);
                count(0) <= count(1);
                c_out <= count(0);
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
    PH_reg_out <= count;
END behavioral;
```

Comment: Don't use `else` or `elsif` after `IF (clk'EVENT AND clk = '1')`. Besides, use `rising_edge(clk)` instead of `clk'EVENT AND clk = '1'`. Read [HERE](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/04/difference-between-risingedgeclk-and.html) why. I can't give you detailed answer, because you provided only a part of the code, and didn't explain what it should do. Provide [mcve].

Comment: `ELSIF (SHR_EN = '1') THEN` is outside the reset and clock edge conditions, it's form not recognized for synthesis. Move it and the following assignments inside the preceding end if so it's registered. Remove SHR_EN from the process sensitivity list.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who commented. I realize now that I posted impulsively and did not adhere to providing a "minimal, complete, and verifiable" question.

Comment: *I know this error has been encountered several times on SO ...* Dozens, but not apparently one with a shift register. A scan through 20 or so show they predominately occur from misplaces if statement parts like yours.

Comment: I see. I probably could have solved this myself from the other examples if I took a little more care. Regardless I hope this post helps someone else!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ELSIF (SHR_EN = '1') THEN` is outside the reset and clock edge conditions, it's form not recognized for synthesis.

Move it and the following assignments inside the preceding end if so it's registered. Remove SHR_EN from the process sensitivity list.

Also in VHDL a name can't start with a number, `5bit_PHreg_vhdl` is invalid as an entity name.

Fixing these and filling in the missing entity declaration:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity PH_reg_5_bit is
    port (
        reset:      in  std_logic;
        clk:        in  std_logic;
        LD_EN:      in  std_logic;
        SHR_EN:     in  std_logic;
        FA_in:      in  std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
        c_in:       in  std_logic;
        c_out:      out std_logic;
        PH_reg_out: out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF PH_reg_5_bit IS
    SIGNAL count    :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN
    PROCESS (reset, clk) -- , SHR_EN)
        BEGIN
-- Check if asynchronous reset is 0
        IF reset = '0' THEN --ERROR OCCURS HERE
                count <= "00000";
-- Check if rising edge
        ELSIF (clk'EVENT AND clk = '1') THEN
                IF LD_EN = '1' THEN
                    count <= FA_in;
        -- Check if SHR_EN is active
                ELSIF (SHR_EN = '1') THEN
                        count(4) <= c_in;
                        count(3) <= count(4);
                        count(2) <= count(3);
                        count(1) <= count(2);
                        count(0) <= count(1);
                END IF;
-- -- Check if SHR_EN is active
--         ELSIF (SHR_EN = '1') THEN
--                 count(4) <= c_in;
--                 count(3) <= count(4);
--                 count(2) <= count(3);
--                 count(1) <= count(2);
--                 count(0) <= count(1);
--                 c_out <= count(0);
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;

    c_out <= count(0);  -- c_out not separately registered
    PH_reg_out <= count;
END behavioral;
```

and your code analyzes successfully.

The entity name is a good indication you haven't simulated your design.

Note the order of conditions implies loading has priority over shifting.

I'd suspect `c_out` should not be registered allowing shift register instances to be concatenated into a larger shift register using c_in and c_out. This means it's assignment should be outside the if statement containing the clock edge event, it can go next to the other output pin assignment.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I have fixed my code. JSYK the name only started with a number because the original name began with my actual name and for the sake of anonymity I removed it. I realize now that my profile actually displays my name sooooo it was an unjustified move!